# Entity Framework Core 2 access token in DBcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to access the current user in the DB context using IHttpContextAccessor. I am using JWT tokens to authenticate.

However the user is always null even when I am logged in. I can access the user details from the controller with no problem.

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    public ClientResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string GetUser()
    {

        return _context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }    
    return _context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
```

I have added

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

to the startup.cs

Is it possible to access the token in the DBContext ?

Comment: Do you try to inject your service 
 as `services.AddTransient<ClientResolverService>();` to the startup.cs?

Comment: Yes I have added 'services.AddTransient<ClientResolverService>();' to the startup.cs?